# Dynamically updating a time stamp value when an object is edited

Tags: c#, datetime, dynamic, timestamp, asp.net-mvc-5

I have coded a C# MVC5 Internet application and have a question in regards to updating a time stamp for objects for when they are edited.

I have many objects in the MVC application. Whenever an object is created, edited or deleted I am manually adding code to the relevant controller to update a timestamp datetime value for the relevant object.

Is there a way to do this dynamically via code?

For example, I have an object that has a list of other objects. Whenever an object is edited in the list, I wish to update the timestamp of the list object, as well as the object that has the list. I can do this manually, yet I am sure there must be a way to do this dynamically.

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently, I am manually retrieving the parent object, and manually updating the time stamp. First of all, is it possible to do the update dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use some DB to store your object, i suppose you implement(or should to implement) some Repository to save all objects in one code part your programm. So you can inherits all you model from some TimeStampEntity, that will have TimeStamp property, and update this property before saving in DB,like:

```
public void SaveOrUpdate<T>(T model)
{
if(model is TimeStampEntity) 
{
((TimeStampEntity)model).TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
repository.SaveOrUpdate(model)
}
```

Hope, it help. Thank you!